# How to prioritize data based on a given value

Tags: php, mysql

Hi is there a way I can prioritize the order by of an sql result?

Example I have a `$_POST['city_id']` request that has a value of `2`, `5` and my table I had a rows of `city_id` of `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`

And when I use the query below example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY city_id ASC
```

I can get a result of `2`,`5`,`1`,`3`,`4` in an order by of a `city_id`.

Comment: Your question is unclear, kindly add more inputs to your question so that we can understand it better and help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by whether the value was in the array (using an `IN` expression) and then by `city_id`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE status = 0 
ORDER BY city_id IN (2, 5) DESC, city_id ASC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=34bf2f28bbe11c6865030f5d245c209e)

Comment: @Nick I just want to know if it make the index on city_id not to work, suppose there is an index on city_id.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I can't say for certain. Since it would use it if the `IN` expression was in the `WHERE` clause, I would imagine it would in an `ORDER BY` clause too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY FIELD``

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY FIELD(city_id, 5,2) DESC, city_id ASC
```

Note that you have to use reverse order in the `FIELD` function if order of the selected items is important.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will put 1, 3 and 4 before 1 and 5 as `FIELD` will return `0`. Using `DESC` will not work either as that will put 5 before 1.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=39b4dcf7d881ef2313657d13533e296c

Comment: I forgot the `DESC` in the first clause of `ORDER BY` indeed. That's corrected. See : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b3e8c47a69df030357c05a88a0a6e7d2

Comment: As you have seen yourself, the result depends on the order of the parameters...

Comment: Yes, otherwise there would be ambiguity : `FIELD(5,5,2)` returns `1`, `(2,5,2)` returns `2`, and for the rest `0`. Then, for all 0s it is the second clause that is applied . I'm not sure what you mean.